# Draw f(x)=0 if x<=1 else (x-1)*(x-1) with matplotlib, and make clear the part f(x)=0 when x<=1

Tags: python, matplotlib, draw

I want to use matplotlib to draw the graph of

```
 f(x)=0 if x<=1 else (x-1)*(x-1)
```

The difficulty is that the part f(x)=0 when x<=1 overlaps with the x-axis. How can I make that part more clear? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can control the color or thickness of the line using

```
matplotlib.pyplot.plot(x,y,c='green',lw=2)
```

where the value of `c` is the color and `lw` gives the linewidth. Default linewidth is 1, which blends in with the axis line. See the pyplot [tutorial](http://matplotlib.org/users/pyplot_tutorial.html) for basics. Another option is to change the limits of the yaxis:

```
matplotlib.pyplot.ylim(-.1,1)
```

it all depends on what style of plot you're going for.